# Trying to create a program that reads an array and prints the prime numbers

Tags: c++

This is what I wrote so far, where did I go wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x[5], count=0;
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
cin>>x[i];

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
for (int n=2;n<x[i];n++)
    {
    if (x[i]%n==0)
    count++;
    }    
if (count==1)
cout<<x[i]<<" ";
}
}
```

Edit:
Many thanks to everyone that tried to help. The problem was that I had to int count in the loop so that it would start from 0 every time. Here's my new working code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x[5];
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
cin>>x[i];

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{ int count=0;
    for (int n=2;n<=x[i];n++)
    {
    if (x[i]%n==0)
    count++;
    }    
if (count==1)
cout<<x[i];
}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're noticing?

Comment: A tiny program like this is actually a great opportunity for making yourself familiar with a debugger. You can execute the code line by line and inspect the values of variables to learn where the program behaves different from your expectation.

Comment: Hint: isolate out the part that actually does the prime test: build a `bool isPrime(unsigned n)`, and go from there. There are more efficient ways of doing this, but this one will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x[5], count=0;
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
cin>>x[i];

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    bool check = true;
    for (int n=2;n<x[i];n++)
    {
        if (x[i]%n==0)
        {
            check = false;
            break;
        }
    }    
    if (check)
    cout<<x[i]<<" ";
}
}
```

For better complexity, change your nested for loop to :

```
for (int n=2;n<=sqrt(x[i]);n++)
```

Other way :

```
int main () 
{
    for (int i=2; i<100; i++) 
    {
        bool check=true;
        for (int n=2; n*n<=x[i]; n++)
        {
            if (x[i] % n == 0) 
            {
                check=false;
                break;    
            }
        }   
        if(check) cout << x[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But why compute `sqrt` at all? Let alone repeatedly (assuming no compiler optimisations). What's wrong with `n * n <= x[i]`?

Comment: If you separated out the primality test from the iteration over the array, and dropped the `n < x[i]` altogether, this may well attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution.
I basically assume all numbers are prime, but if I find them not to be prime I don't print them out.

```
int main()  {
    bool primeNumber;
    int length = 0;
    int x[5], count=0;

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        length++;
        cin>>x[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0;  i < length;  i++ )
    {
        primeNumber = true;
        for (int j = 3;  j <= x[i]/2;  j += 2 )//Not necessary to check agains numbers higher than half the number you want to check
        {

        if (x[i] % j == 0) 
        {
            primeNumber = false;
        }
    }
    if(primeNumber){cout << "Primenumber: " << x[i] << endl;}
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here's a comment on your code
Let's say your array looks like this

```
{5,9,13,15, 17}



int main()
{
    int x[5], count=0;
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    cin>>x[i];

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)   
    {
        for (int n=2;n<x[i];n++)
        {
```

> Here you loop from 2-4(2,3,4). It's only necessary to loop half the number you want to check. e.g. (x[i]/2), but you can do it like you have done here.

```
            if (x[i]%n==0){       
            count++;}
```

> When your number is 5 and you check agains n numbers This will produce 5%2=1,5%3=2,5%4=1. *But 5 is a prime number* and your code didn't manage to detect that.

```
        }    
    if (count==1)
```

> Let's say you did find that 5 is a prime above and you managed to increment count to 1. What happens when you find another prime number in your array e.g. 7. That will make count be equal to 2. But you only check against 1, so therefor your next prime number doesn't get printed because count will only be equal to 1 after the first prime number and not the rest.

```
    cout<<x[i]<<" ";
    }
```

}

Hopefully you understood my explanation. It always helps to go over your code by hand or debug mode and think what the code will do with different numbers.

Comment: thank you all for your replies. Can someone explain to me why my original code does not detect the prime numbers properly?
In the nested loop, I started from 2 up to the number n and the count would increase by one each time the remainder is 0. (Basically, the prime numbers would only be divisible by itself) and then cout x[i] within the main loop. Where exactly did I go wrong in this?

Comment: I have finally found out what was wrong after reading your comment. I added int count in the main loop instead of at the beginning, that way every time the count starts from 0. I am very grateful for your help, I spent days trying to make it work and having no clue.

Comment: I was trying to optimize the code by only doing half the numbers (x[i]/2) as you stated but seems that won't work out. I need the final number in the loop which is the prime number itself so that I can increase the count by 1.

Comment: If you try to divide all numbers by itself you will find that your code will believe all numbers are prime.

Answer (score 0):

All numers are divideable by itself. That will make all numbers prime if you try to divide numbers with themselves